# The DropDown Menu get cut off when parent have overflow

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, overflow

I created a DropDown menu, I used my real project source code for it so that there should be no confusion:-

```css
.main-container {
  overflow-x: auto;
}

div.btn-dropdown-options {
    font-family: "Haas Grot Text R Web", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 20px;
    
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
    top: calc(100% + 8px);
    left: 0;
    min-width: 180px;
    margin-top: 4px;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    border-radius: 8px;
    background: #fff;
    visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 2s, visibility 2s;
    
    
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(128,138,157,0.12),0px 8px 32px rgba(128,138,157,0.24);
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(128,138,157,0.12),0px 8px 32px rgba(128,138,157,0.24);
}
```

I have a dropdown menu **div.btn-dropdown-options** and a parent container **main-container**. When I click on the toggle button to show the dropdown it gets cut off due to overflow property, I have used position: absolute and z-index: 1000;, but nothing is working, how can I show the dropdown menu above the overflow?

full-code :- https://jsfiddle.net/ur5sL4qv/

Answer (score 0):

1. it will be resolved by assigning height to main-container

`.main-container {overflow-x: auto; height: 100vh;}`

or

2. Use position relative instead of absolute in div.btn-dropdown-options

`div.btn-dropdown-options {position: relative;}`

Comment: 1. It will increase the height of the container, I don't to have a height to the container
2. It will push the container down and I also don't want that, I want to make the dropdown on top of the overflow without height

Comment: 1. Use your main-container for remaining stuff and it will work fine. OR  Change `.main-container {overflow: visible;}`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully understand the problem (I suggest using background colors for signaling what's undesireable). But does removing `overflow-x` from .main-container and adding `position: absolute` to dropdown options fixes your issue?

```
.btn-dropdown .btn-dropdown-options {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: When I remove overflow-x, the dropdown is showing, but I want to use the overflow property, what can I do, I am not able to find any solution for this problem